# Can I use Google voice search to recognise voice in background?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I have learned the sample code of Android ApiDemos, the following code can recognise voice using  Google voice search when I speak to microphone.

But there are some problems with  Google voice search, Google voice search must be online to work.

I have saved my voice to a file, how can I make Google voice search to  recognise the voice file and return result?

```
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                matches));
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the Google speech recognizer to operate on anything other than the mic with the provided APIs.  As well, there is no official way to use the underlying web service either, though there is an unofficial way based on the chromium source code.

If you want to do speech recognition offline, you can run [PocketSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx) on the device.  Or, you can try to find an online API that you can use for speech recognition, but most of the major ones are either unavailable for licensing or very expensive.